# Modifying an XML file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

Consider a XML document

```
 <string id = "id1" ><p> Text1 </p>
<p> Text 3 <\p>

</string>
    <string id = "id2" > Text2 </string>
```

I want to update the contents of string tag i.e replacing "Text1" with "Apple" and "Text2" with "boy". As I have mentioned in the first statement "Text1" is not directly encapsulated in string tag , it is encapsulated directly in some other tag (here it is `<p>` but in input file it can be any arbitrary tag or inside `<p>` tag there can be one more tag and inside that there will be `"Text1"`

I tried to to do it but could accomplish to change only "Text2" as it was directly encapsulated in string tag

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file.xml"));

result = {}
doc.xpath("//string").each do |node|
        id_value = node.get_attribute "id"
        puts "##############"
        puts node
        node.content = "a"
        puts "%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
        puts node
end
```

Can somebody please suggest me a way to modify "Text1" in my example.

---

Comment: That isn't a valid XML document. It's missing a root node.

Comment: Does your actual XML have a root node? Or do you want to update a an XML "fragment"?

Answer (score 0):

Below there is an idea, how to do it. This program iterates for all `string` nodes and when the node has a non-text child, it replaces the child content. It works for your example (notice I had to surround your XML with `<xml>` tag) as expected but, again, treat it as an idea.

```
require 'nokogiri'
xml = "<xml><string id = \"id1\" ><p> Text1 </p></string>\n<string id = \"id2\" > Text2 </string></xml>"
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)
doc.xpath('//string').each do |s|
  case s.child
  when Nokogiri::XML::Text
    s.content = "boy"
  when Nokogiri::XML::Element
    s.child.content = "Apple"
  end
end
puts doc.to_xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><string id="id1"><p>Apple</p></string>
<string id="id2">boy</string></xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using `xpath`'s [`text()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) and [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space):

```
doc.css("text()[normalize-space()='Text1']").each { |n| n.content = "Apple" }
doc.css("text()[normalize-space()='Text2']").each { |n| n.content = "boy" }
puts doc.to_s
# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <xml><string id="id1"><p>Apple</p></string>
# <string id="id2">boy</string></xml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because neither of the other two answers actually works correctly for all of the op's possibilities, I modified both answers:

Common code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

#Setting Nokogiri's parser options on the following line to strict(the default) 
#and noblanks tells Nokogiri to ignore Text nodes that contain only whitespace:

xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(<<END_OF_XML) { |config| config.strict.noblanks }
<root>
<not>Text1</not>

<string id = "id1" >
  <p> Text1 </p>
  <p> Text 3 </p>
</string>

<string id = "id2" > Text2 </string>

<string id="id3">
  <p><p><p>Text1</p></p></p>
</string>

<not>Text2</not>
</root>
END_OF_XML
```

1) The normalize-space answer is no different than:

```
new_xml = xml_doc.to_s.gsub('Text1', 'Apple').gsub('Text2', 'boy')
```

Here are some changes so that substitutions only occur inside `<string>` tags:

```
xml_doc.xpath('//string').each do |string_tag|
  string_tag.css(
    "text()[normalize-space()='Text1']"
  ).each { |n| n.content = "Apple" }

  string_tag.css(
    "text()[normalize-space()='Text2']"
  ).each { |n| n.content = "boy" }
end

puts xml_doc.to_s


--output:--
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<not>Text1</not>

<string id="id1">
  <p>Apple</p>
  <p> Text 3 </p>
</string>

<string id="id2">boy</string>

<string id="id3">
  <p><p><p>Apple</p></p></p>
</string>

<not>Text2</not>
</root>
```

You could also write it like this:

```
xml_doc.xpath("//string//text()[normalize-space()='Text1']"
  ).each { |n| n.content = "Apple" }

xml_doc.xpath("//string//text()[normalize-space()='Text2']"
  ).each { |n| n.content = "boy" }

puts xml_doc.to_s
```

But then you have to search the whole xml_doc twice, and I thought it might be more efficient to search each string tag for both texts at once.

The original answer also uses undocumented(as far as I can tell) xpaths with the css() method.  According to the docs, the argument to css() needs to be a css selector, and an xpath is not a css selector, so using an xpath shouldn't work.

2)  The case statement answer is a bit different because it was not clear from your post whether you are searching for specific text or whether you want an immediate text node replaced with "boy", and a nested text node replaced with "Apple".

```
def get_base_text_node(node)
  child_node = node.child

  case child_node
    when Nokogiri::XML::Text
      child_node
    when Nokogiri::XML::Element
      get_base_text_node(child_node)
  end

end

xml_doc.xpath('//string').each do |s|
  case s.child
  when Nokogiri::XML::Text
    s.content = "boy"
  else
    text_node = get_base_text_node(s)
    text_node.content = "Apple"
  end
end


puts xml_doc.to_xml

--output:--

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <not>Text1</not>
  <string id="id1">
    <p>Apple</p>
    <p> Text 3 </p>
  </string>
  <string id="id2">boy</string>
  <string id="id3">
    <p>
      <p>
        <p>Apple</p>
      </p>
    </p>
  </string>
  <not>Text2</not>
</root>
```